# Shopify Liquid tag modify HTML?

Tags: shopify, liquid, pagespeed, shopify-app

I have shopify store. I want to amend HTML output of app.

basically app adds some `Img` tag which is not visible to client via CSS. I want to remove those `Img` tags from it.

> {% include 'my-appinfo', app-arg-1: 'test' %}

As above we include app into `theme.liquid` file.

Comment: Are you sure that the added image is with liquid logic and not with JS logic?

Comment: What is your question? If you want to remove <img> tags from the snippet, just remove them. What is the problem?